# using casperjs with selenium webdriver and Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, casperjs

Edit:
I have below casperjs script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://google.com/', function() {
print(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
print(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

I tried to run this script using below command in Java:

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/PhantomJS/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs download.js");
```

The code compiles and run but there is no output.

I tried using Script engine eval function:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/resources/CasperTest.js"));
```

But in this case i get below exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:455)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:439)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:401)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:397)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:147)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
    at loginpage.main(loginpage.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: <eval>:1 ReferenceError: "require" is not defined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.__noSuchProperty__(Global.java:914)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:636)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:229)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:387)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:437)
    ... 10 more
[INFO  - 2017-05-12T07:27:05.869Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
```

How can I execute the my casperjs script?

Comment: Have you looked at their documentation on the respective sites?

Comment: yes i have referred casperjs site. they have given few examples for testing using casperjs scripts. But they are different script files which are executed through cli. What i am expecting is to embed the downloading functionality within the existing code

Comment: _"What i am expecting is to embed the downloading functionality within the existing code"_ what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not make sense...

1. **CasperJS** is a JavaScript library which allows you to automate **PhantomJS** (headless WebKit) or **SlimerJS** (graphical Gecko). It has not been designed to control Chrome or Firefox through Selenium WebDriver...
2. If you want to use Selenium WebDriver with JavaScript, you should rely on a framework like **Nightwatch.js** which makes it possible to control *real* web browsers.
3. **Casper** or **Nightwatch** scripts are completely independent from your back-end in Java. You can create a separate folder in your project and put your JS scripts in there.

Comment: ok means we can have a separate casper script file which can be called when required